Ubuntu nfs mount to client which includes sub-folders that are mounts themselves not working
I have 3 Ubuntu 20.04 servers. The main one (Server01) contains a folder in the root called /mydata. In this folder are some sub-folders, one of which is an nfs mount from another Ubuntu server (Server02).
Server01
├── media
├── mnt
├── mydata
│   └── clientinfo (nfs mount from Server02)
│   └── misc
├── opt
├── proc

Server02
├── boot
├── cdrom
├── clientinfo (exported to Server01)
├── etc

I want to mount the /mydata folder from Server01 on to another server (Server03), so I export it from Server01 like so:
/mydata 10.0.0.3(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)

When I nfs mount this on Server03, I only see the following structure (i.e. the clientinfo folder is not there):
Server03
├── media
├── mnt
├── mydata
│   └── misc
├── opt
├── proc

My fstab on Server03 looks like this:
10.0.0.1:/mydata /mydata nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr 0 0

Perhaps naively I assumed whatever was within the /mydata folder on Server01 would transfer through when mounted to another client. The /mydata/misc folder appears just fine, but the mounted folder from Server02 (clientinfo) just will not appear.
What can I do to this configuration to get all the directories to appear on Server03?

What NFS version is being used for the mount from Server03?

Version 4 on all 3 servers. All 3 servers are also running Ubuntu 20.04

Can you try explicitly exporting /mydata/clientinfo via NFS? I think that's required for the Linux NFS server (as it really works at a level slightly below VFS).
